# Can I make a Vim mapping for a single file?

Tags: vim, mapping

Basically I would like to be able to quickly look up Vim's help pages for specific commands. To do that, I am using this mapping:

```
nnoremap K :help <C-r><C-w><CR>
```

However, I would like to apply this mapping **only to my `.vimrc`** (in order to be able to use different lookup documentations for different files).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`K` already does keyword lookup but the associated `'keywordprg'` option is rarely defined.

Add the snippet below to your `~/.vimrc` to get the desired behavior:

```
augroup vim
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType vim setlocal keywordprg=:help
augroup END
```

---

Thanks for reminding me to set it up correctly in my own config.